# Appending a new field value to a related table

Tags: ms-access

[ms- access]

I have two tables one called tblContracts and one called tblClientName.

tblClientName contains a list of uniquely named clients.

tblContracts has a list of contracts each of which are assigned a client name, contracts can have the same client names.

In my relationships tool I have setup a many(tblContracts) to one(tblClientName) relationship between the two tables. Both using the field ClientName.

When I enter a new client name(one that doesn't currently exist in tblClientName) into tblContracts I want tblClientName to automatically append this name.

What is the best way to achieve this?

KR

Chris

Comment: You can't. That's the point of Referential Integrity - a contract cannot exist without having a client assigned. So, first create the client, then the contract. Also, don't use the name as key, use an Id set to _Autonumber_ values in the client table and _Long_ in the contract table.

Comment: Thanks Gustav, I had a feeling that the using the name as the key was bad practice. But why if the name is unique? Also you are correct a contract cannot exist without a client name, but why cant the client name be created automatically?

Comment: Don't count on names being unique. Also, if clients are individuals, name parts should be in separate fields. How should Access even know that entering a new name in contracts table should be added into clients table as well as how? Select client from combobox list. Explore the NotInList event of combobox to create new client record 'on the fly' during contract data entry.

Comment: Ok, the not in list event was what I was looking for thanks June7. Regarding the client names, they have to be unique (they are company names), I do not want a user entering two client names that are the same, so I still don't see the need for an auto number ID.

Comment: Numeric keys are more efficient for indexing and require less storage. If you need to change the customer name (misspelling or legal change) don't have to modify a ton of records, only change the one parent record that has the client name.

Comment: Although, I guess Cascade Update in relationship could deal with name change.

Comment: Thanks again June7. The NotInList event is working great, when I enter new values into the combox box, it updates the client table perfectly. However..... If I paste multiple records into the contractor table, this event is not triggered?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236309/discussion-between-user1870218-and-june7).